# Greek Language Issue

Tags: overleaf, greek

I am writing my master's degree thesis in English. Although, I have to include abstract in Greek and I would like also to include it at the table of contents. Below the main code of tex is portrayed. Tex

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pagestyle{fancy}



%\title{Modern Investment Strategies in Hedge Funds}
%\author{Nikolaos Minas}
%\date{September 2022}


\begin{document}
%\begin{titlepage}

\include{Titlepage}
%\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
%\end{titlepage}
%\maketitle
%\newpage
\tableofcontents
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Modern Investment Strategies in Hedge Funds}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Nikolaos Minas - MXAN2016}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=period,font=footnotesize,labelfont={bf}}
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\include{Introduction}

\include{Chapter1}

\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4} 
\include{Chapter5} 

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Tex Introduction contains the script in both english and greek.However, in Greek the font is not the same as in English whereas several letters are missing. Any ideas ?

```
    \section*{Abstract}
The scope of this dissertation is to prepare a thorough analysis of the hedge funds industry in order to examine the size and the performance of the market. This analysis was conducted by both a literature review and an empirical analysis of publicly available data and more specifically from Hedge Funds Research database. Examination of the hedge fund industry was conducted by calculating Sharpe Ratio, Sortino Ratio, Value at Risk as well as by applying a linear regression using the Jensen model. 
\paragraph{}
Our conclusions indicate that the aggregate performance of hedge funds throughout the period of 2010-2021 presented a notable decline, a fact which is observed in both literature review and the empirical analysis. The dissertation is divided into five chapters for better understanding. Initially, Chapter 1 is an introductory to the Hedge Funds, its characteristics, and their limitations as an asset class. Chapter 2 provides a thorough description of each hedge fund strategy. Chapter 3 indicates a literature review among the size and performance of hedge funds. Next comes Chapter 4 which presents the empirical analysis applied in order to determine the performance of hedge funds. Finally, Chapter 5 concludes the thesis and presents the main outcomes as well as its limitations and the suggestions for possible future research. 
\newpage
\section*{\textbf{Περίληψη}}
\paragraph{}
O σκοπός της παρούσας μεταπτυχιακής εργασίας είναι η ανάλυση των Hedge Funds ως προς τόσο το μέγεθός τους σαν επενδυτικό προϊόν όσο και οι επιδόσεις τους. Για την ανάλυση λήφθηκε υπόψιν τόσο η υφιστάμενη βιβλιογραφία, όσο και μια ανάλυση δεδομένων τα οποία προέκυψαν από την βάση δεδομένων Hedge Funds Research Database. Η εν λόγω ανάλυση βασίστηκε στον προσδιορισμό των Sharpe Ratio Sortino Ratio, Value at Risk, καθώς και της εφαρμογής μιας γραμμικής παλινδρόμησης βάσει του μοντέλου του Jensen. 
\paragraph{}
Από την παρούσα έρευνα ως κύριο συμπέρασμα προέκυψε το γεγονός ότι τα hedge funds από το 2010 έως το 2021 παρουσιάζουν μια σημαντική πτώση ως προς την απόδοσή τους, γεγονός που αντικατοπτρίζεται τόσο στην βιβλιογραφική όσο και στην εμπειρική έρευνα. Η παρούσα μεταπτυχιακή έργασία χωρίζεται σε πέντε κεφάλαια με σκοπό την καλύτερη κατανόηση του αντικείμένου που πραγματεύεται η παρούσα για τον εκάστοτε αναγνώστη. Το πρώτο κεφάλαιο αποτελείται από μια εισαγωγή ως προς τα Hedge Funds, τα χαρακτηριστικά τους καθώς και τους περιορισμούς που τα διακατέχουν. Στη συνέχεια το δεύτερο κεφάλαιο παρουσιάζει μια αναλυτική αναφορά ως προς τις κύριες στρατηγικές των Hedge Funds. Το τρίτο κεφάλαιο αναλύει την βιβλιογραφική ανασκόπηση και καταλήγει στον προσδιορισμό τόσο του μεγέθους των Hedge Funds όσο και της αποδοτικότητάς τους. Επόμενο είναι το τέταρτο κεφάλαιο, στο οποίο γίνεται αναφορά στην ανάλυση δεδομένων για τον προσδιορισό των αποδόσεων των hedge funds. Τέλος, το κεφάλαιο 5 ολοκληρώνει την παρούσα έρευνα και παρουσιάζει τα κύρια συμπεράσματα που προέκυψαν, τους περιορισμούς καθώς και ορισμένες προτάσεις του συγγραφέα για τυχόν μελλοντική έρευνα.
```

Comment: Are you compiling with XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX? You're loading the `babel` package twice. The `hyperref` package should be loaded last. If you're using XeLaTeX, you don't need the `inputenc` package and I highly doubt you need `ucs` or `textgreek` packages. How wedded are you to `cmbright` as a font? I doubt it has the characters you need. If cmbright isn't a requirement, drop it, and try loading the `fontspec` package and set the font to something unicode-compliant with full coverage of Greek.

Comment: And for the purposes of this post, it's probably best to whittle your code down to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that); as is, we cannot compile your code, since it requires `\input`ed files and a bibliography we do not have.

Comment: Since your thesis has chapters, `article` is a strange choice for document class. Try something with chapters, like `book`. Move `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}` from the main file into the Introduction.tex and put it right before the opening `\section*` command. You can add a similar `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Περίληψη}` after `\newpage` before the next `\section*`. No need for `\textbf{...}` there as section headings should already be bold.

Comment: `\paragraph` is used as a sectioning command below subsubsection, not as a simple paragraph break. For a simple paragraph break, just leave a blank line or use `\par`.

Comment: Try using `\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}` before the Greek and `\end{otherlanguage}` after ortherwise, or use other means provided by babel for specifying the language to get proper hypenation rules, etc. [This article from Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_babel_and_fontspec) might be of some use.

Comment: Many thanks for oyur tips. Howeve, I still struggle to contain greek in my thesis. Unfortunately, none of your insightful suggestions have worked. More specifically, in the greek abstract section only several greek letters are portrayed.

Comment: Are you using xelatex and if so, with what font? If you're still having problems, a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that can actually be compiled as is would still be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to fix, but here's the idea.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed 
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
%\usepackage{textgreek}% not needed
\usepackage{cmbright} 
%\usepackage{ucs}% obsolete
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption} 
%\usepackage{float}% don't use [H]
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  width=150mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=6mm,
  headheight=15pt, % <- as asked by fancyhdr
}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\rmdefault}{neohellenic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Modern Investment Strategies in Hedge Funds}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Nikolaos Minas - MXAN2016}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=period,font=footnotesize,labelfont={bf}}


%\title{Modern Investment Strategies in Hedge Funds}
%\author{Nikolaos Minas}
%\date{September 2022}


\begin{document}

%\begin{titlepage}

%\include{Titlepage}
%\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
%\end{titlepage}
%\maketitle
%\newpage

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

The scope of this dissertation is to prepare a thorough analysis of the hedge funds 
industry in order to examine the size and the performance of the market. This analysis 
was conducted by both a literature review and an empirical analysis of publicly 
available data and more specifically from Hedge Funds Research database. 
Examination of the hedge fund industry was conducted by calculating Sharpe Ratio, 
Sortino Ratio, Value at Risk as well as by applying a linear regression using the 
Jensen model. 

Our conclusions indicate that the aggregate performance of hedge funds throughout the 
period of 2010-2021 presented a notable decline, a fact which is observed in both 
literature review and the empirical analysis. The dissertation is divided into 
five chapters for better understanding. Initially, Chapter 1 is an introductory 
to the Hedge Funds, its characteristics, and their limitations as an asset class. 
Chapter 2 provides a thorough description of each hedge fund strategy. Chapter 3 
indicates a literature review among the size and performance of hedge funds. 
Next comes Chapter 4 which presents the empirical analysis applied in order 
to determine the performance of hedge funds. Finally, Chapter 5 concludes the 
thesis and presents the main outcomes as well as its limitations and the suggestions 
for possible future research. 

\clearpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Περίληψη}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Περίληψη}}

\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
O σκοπός της παρούσας μεταπτυχιακής εργασίας είναι η ανάλυση των 
\foreignlanguage{english}{Hedge Funds} ως προς τόσο το μέγεθός τους σαν επενδυτικό 
προϊόν όσο και οι επιδόσεις τους. Για την ανάλυση λήφθηκε υπόψιν τόσο η υφιστάμενη 
βιβλιογραφία, όσο και μια ανάλυση δεδομένων τα οποία προέκυψαν από την βάση δεδομένων 
\foreignlanguage{english}{Hedge Funds Research Database}. Η εν λόγω ανάλυση βασίστηκε 
στον προσδιορισμό των \foreignlanguage{english}{Sharpe Ratio Sortino Ratio}, 
\foreignlanguage{english}{Value at Risk}, καθώς και της εφαρμογής μιας γραμμικής 
παλινδρόμησης βάσει του μοντέλου του Jensen. 

Από την παρούσα έρευνα ως κύριο συμπέρασμα προέκυψε το γεγονός ότι τα 
\foreignlanguage{english}{hedge funds} από το 2010 έως το 2021 παρουσιάζουν μια 
σημαντική πτώση ως προς την απόδοσή τους, γεγονός που αντικατοπτρίζεται τόσο στην 
βιβλιογραφική όσο και στην εμπειρική έρευνα. Η παρούσα μεταπτυχιακή έργασία 
χωρίζεται σε πέντε κεφάλαια με σκοπό την καλύτερη κατανόηση του αντικείμένου 
που πραγματεύεται η παρούσα για τον εκάστοτε αναγνώστη. Το πρώτο κεφάλαιο 
αποτελείται από μια εισαγωγή ως προς τα \foreignlanguage{english}{Hedge Funds}, 
τα χαρακτηριστικά τους καθώς και τους περιορισμούς που τα διακατέχουν. Στη συνέχεια 
το δεύτερο κεφάλαιο παρουσιάζει μια αναλυτική αναφορά ως προς τις κύριες στρατηγικές 
των \foreignlanguage{english}{Hedge Funds}. Το τρίτο κεφάλαιο αναλύει την βιβλιογραφική 
ανασκόπηση και καταλήγει στον προσδιορισμό τόσο του μεγέθους των Hedge Funds όσο και 
της αποδοτικότητάς τους. Επόμενο είναι το τέταρτο κεφάλαιο, στο οποίο γίνεται αναφορά 
στην ανάλυση δεδομένων για τον προσδιορισό των αποδόσεων των hedge funds. Τέλος, το 
κεφάλαιο 5 ολοκληρώνει την παρούσα έρευνα και παρουσιάζει τα κύρια συμπεράσματα που 
προέκυψαν, τους περιορισμούς καθώς και ορισμένες προτάσεις του συγγραφέα για τυχόν 
μελλοντική έρευνα. 
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A working minimal example for pdfLaTeX.

- With pdfLaTeX, you need to protext Latin letters in Greek text!
  Wrap non-Greek words in `\ensureascii{ }` or use LuaTeX and Unicode fonts.
- In a mixed-language document under pdfLaTeX, Greek sections in the ToC are tricky and may interfere with indexing (makeindex, xindy...).
  Changing to Greek language only *inside* the `\section` or `\addcontentsline` command should help. Switching to LuaTeX helps, too.
- Font setup is a stub, the fonts do not match.

Main document:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not required since 2018
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
% \usepackage{textgreek}  % not required, conflicts possible

\usepackage{cmbright}
% select a font that also supports Greek
% (alternatively, use \DeclareFontfamilySubstitution to set up
% a matching Greek text font)
\usepackage{gfsneohellenic} 
% \usepackage{ucs} % conflict
% \usepackage{babel} % already loaded
\usepackage{graphicx}
% [...] % packages not required for the minimal example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\include{Introduction}

% [...] % add your chapters.
\end{document}
```

And Introduction.tex

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\section*{Abstract}

The scope of this dissertation is to prepare a thorough analysis of the
hedge funds industry …

Our conclusions indicate that the aggregate performance of hedge funds
throughout the period of 2010-2021 presented a notable decline, …
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Περίληψη}}
\selectlanguage{greek}
\section*{Περίληψη}

% Warning: With pdfLaTeX, you need to protext Latin letters in Greek text!
%          Wrap non-Greek words in \ensureascii{ }
%          or use LuaTeX and Unicode fonts.

O σκοπός της παρούσας μεταπτυχιακής εργασίας είναι η ανάλυση των 
\ensureascii{Hedge Funds} ως προς τόσο το μέγεθός τους σαν επενδυτικό προϊόν
όσο και οι επιδόσεις τους. Για την ανάλυση λήφθηκε υπόψιν τόσο η υφιστάμενη
βιβλιογραφία, όσο και μια ανάλυση δεδομένων τα οποία προέκυψαν από την βάση
δεδομένων \ensureascii{Hedge Funds Research Database}. Η εν λόγω ανάλυση
βασίστηκε στον προσδιορισμό των \ensureascii{Sharpe Ratio Sortino Ratio,
Value at Risk}, καθώς και της εφαρμογής μιας γραμμικής παλινδρόμησης βάσει
του μοντέλου του Jensen. 

Από την παρούσα έρευνα ως κύριο συμπέρασμα προέκυψε το γεγονός ότι τα
\ensureascii{hedge funds} από το 2010 έως το 2021 …

\selectlanguage{english}
```